# stop ssh :channel x: open failed: connect failed: connection refused" logging

Tags: ssh

Is there a clean way to stop ssh from echoing the following messages?

```
channel x: open failed: connect failed: connection refused
```

It really messes up interactive consoles, when the tunnels are expected to be intermittent and happen often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following directive in your ssh config file. (Often ~/.ssh/config)

```
Host yourHost
    LogLevel QUIET
```

Note that other logging, besides the one mentioned in this question, may now also be ignored